# Mapping two arrays two one object in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, algorithm, data-structures

I have two different arrays which am trying to map them to one object, using the information in the first array `ModelOne id`. I use two for loops to check if the `id` in model one appears in the second array if true create an object with model one `id`, `name` and array of all names in model two. From my implementation am not able to get the correct results.

```
// Model One
struct ModelOne: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

// Model two
struct ModelTwo: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let modelOneId: Int
    let name: String
}

var arrayOne = [ModelOne]()

arrayOne.append(ModelOne(id: 1, name: "One"))
arrayOne.append(ModelOne(id: 2, name: "Two"))

var arrayTwo = [ModelTwo]()

arrayTwo.append(ModelTwo(id: 1, modelOneId: 1, name: "Some name"))
arrayTwo.append(ModelTwo(id: 2, modelOneId: 1, name: "Other name"))
arrayTwo.append(ModelTwo(id: 1, modelOneId: 2, name: "Name one"))
arrayTwo.append(ModelTwo(id: 2, modelOneId: 2, name: "Name two"))

struct MappedModel {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let items: [String]
}

var arrayThree = [MappedModel]()

for i in arrayOne {
    for x in arrayTwo {
        if i.id == x.id {
            arrayThree.append(MappedModel(id: i.id, name: i.name, items: [x.name]))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm interpreting the issue correctly, you want the `MappedModel` to have the `id` and `name` from `ModelOne`, with `items` containing all of the `name`s from the `ModelTwo` where `modelOneId` matches the `ModelOne` `id`.

If so, this would do the trick:

```
var combined = arrayOne.map { item1 in
    MappedModel(id: item1.id, name: item1.name, items: arrayTwo.compactMap { $0.id == item1.id ? $0.name : nil})
}
```

Which yields:

```
[
  MappedModel(id: 1, name: "One", items: ["Some name", "Other name"]),
  MappedModel(id: 2, name: "Two", items: ["Name one", "Name two"])
]
```

Comment: or using compactMap to avoid iterating the collection twice `items: arrayTwo.compactMap { $0.id == item1.id ? $0.name : nil }`

Comment: Note that OP is not using modelOneId `if i.id == x.id {` but not sure if that's what he needs

Comment: @LeoDabus I did note that. I'm making an assumption (that may be incorrect) that this is one of their issues, based on the naming scheme.

Comment: Yes I did notice that as well

Comment: @LeoDabus good idea with the `compactMap` -- adjusted. @Mzalendo see the revision history to see the original, which may be *slightly* more readable.

Comment: Thank you all for your solution it helped me alot. It looks more optimal than what I had, thank you.